# android setonitemclicklistener to pass multiple values to another activity?

Tags: android, listview

i am new in android so please help me about these problem
How to pass multiple values (like text & image)  of listview to another activity show details view of the list view item selected(clicked) by user?

it gives me a error which is show in the image i have uploaded
[image]

these my setonitemclicklistener function
// Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(ListOfHotels.this, SampleActivity.class);
                // parameters
                i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position + 1));

                /* selected item parameters
                 * 1.   Hotel name
                 * 2.   address
                 * 3.   distance
                 * 4.   icon   
                 */
                i.putExtra("name", hotelDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_NAME));
                i.putExtra("address", hotelDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ADDRESS));
                i.putExtra("distance", hotelDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_DIST));
                i.putExtra("icon", hotelDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON));

                // start the sample activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Comment: is your image online? are you using AsyncTask for web functions?

Comment: post your code and logcat details of the crash

Comment: some relevant snippet of code, as well

Comment: A few tips. It's tricky to tell where the crash is happening. Do you have a stack trace telling you where the crash happened? It could be anything. Also, hotelDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_NAME) is a line of death. If you separate hotelDataCollection.get(position) and save the reference as an object, it'll make things easier to debug

Comment: i resolved the problem. actually i have forget to write the activity in manifest file. thank you very much to take a efforts for me to resolved problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem. actually i have forget to write the activity in manifest file. thank you very much to take a efforts for me to resolved problem

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override   
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Item item = (Item)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String id = String.valueOf(item.getId());
        Bitmap image = id item.getImg();            

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
        byte[] imageByteArray = bos.toByteArray();

        Intent intentDetail = new Intent();

        intentDetail.setClass(getActivity(), OtherActivity.class);
        intentDetail.putExtra("id", id);
        intentDetail.putExtra("img", imageByteArray);                        

        startActivity(intentDetail);            

    }
```

Should be something like that. You will have to put your image into an array of byte to use putExtra i guess.

Answer (score 0):

U can use intent.putExtra("key","value") method for passing data to another activity.

From that activity use getIntent().getExtra("key") method to access that data.

like this

```
     Intent i = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, DetailsScreen.class);
     URL = entries.get(arg2).getLink();
     i.putExtra("type", "json");
     i.putExtra("Url",URL);
     i.putExtra("Header", entries.get(arg2).getTitle());
     startActivity(i);
```

Then

```
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("Url");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the infos of a row in an object, you can pass it to the next activity with  [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) like that :

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("info", object);
            startActivity(i);
```

you must implements [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) in your object class, and when you are in your NextActivity you can do something like that

```
myObject = (MyObject) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("info");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it'll help you.

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(name, value);